# Implementing custom checkable relativelayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want my `RelativeLayout` to show that it is checked. For this I thought a custom `RelativeLayout` would be easiest, that would implement `checkable`. Thus when I clicked an item, this would be called and modify my layout. I thought the easiest would be to highlight it by `setBackgroundColor` to the holo selected blue.

Firstly is there anything wrong with the above? (i.e. does that sound like a good idea?)

Secondly, it works in that an item will be checked and if I call `isChecked` it returns the correct answer. However it doesn't update the RelativeLayout to indicate that it is selected. I assume there is something wrong in my code.

```
public class CustomRL extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

private boolean isChecked;
List<RelativeLayout> rl = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
Context context;

public CustomRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    for (RelativeLayout r : rl)
        r.setBackgroundColor(isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#33b5e5")
                : 0x00000000);
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    for (RelativeLayout r : rl)
        r.setBackgroundColor(this.isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#33b5e5")
                : 0x00000000);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        getRelativeLayout(this.getChildAt(i));
    }
}

private void getRelativeLayout(View v) {
    if (v instanceof RelativeLayout) {
        rl.add((RelativeLayout) v);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `invalidate()` to make sure that the view is being redrawn?

Answer (score 1):

This is important to use this layout properly. First of all when You use it in ListView, you should set

> listView.setItemsCanFocus(false)

and set choice mode either to

> listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)

or

> listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)